# Python Remove Span Tags and Overwrite Txt File

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to remove span tags from a text document before I ping it, or else it will fail, but I cannot get it to remove the span tags and either save the file again without the tag or save the new results into a array to save.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(r'sitelist.txt') as f:
    f = f.read().splitlines()

soup = BeautifulSoup(f,"html.parser")

while len(soup.find_all('span')) > 0:
    soup.span.extract()

f = soup

return f
```

I have tried to decompose or unwrap and cannot get the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah...[`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) return a list, you can't just use `BeautifulSoup()` on a list. Instead, just replace `f = f.read().splitlines()` with `f = f.read()`.

And then, your code works, you just need write the output into a file right?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(r'sitelist.txt') as f:
    f = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")

while len(soup.find_all('span')) > 0:
    soup.span.extract()

with open(r'sitelist.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: That is seeming to delete the entire website link creating gaps in the new text document. But I think we are definitely closing in on a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @CBux: Well, because it just removes all `span` tags from the text file (I think it's a HTML file actually right?). And if this answer is helpful, remember accept it. Please check our [tour] and [help] for more details.

Comment: If it removes the entire line then it kind of sets me back. Is there a way to save the url but just get rid of the span tag that encloses it?

Comment: Got it figured out! instead of:
    soup.span.extract()

I used
    soup.span.unwrap()

Comment: @CBux: Ah yeah, that is. Happy that you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you don't need to use `readline()`, only `read()`.
I'm not sure if extract works, does it?
Here's my solution, it simply removes span tags(which I think is what you asked):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('sitelist.txt', 'r') as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile,"html.parser")
    for match in soup.findAll('span'): 
        match.unwrap()

with open('sitelist.txt', 'w') as html:
    html.write(str(soup))
```

I am sure there is a way to opened a file for both reading and writing, but I just open and reopened the file twice.

Comment: Instead of extract I used unwrap and it removed the tags perfectly. Thanks for the help!